# AndroidPlot Change color of domain and range labels

Tags: android, androidplot

I am using the AndroidPlot library and am trying to change the colour of the domain and range labels.

I set them like so:

```
//Setting the names of the axis
XYPlot.setRangeLabel("# of Alerts");
XYPlot.setDomainLabel("Day");
```

By default they are white but are barely visible against my cream background. Does anyone know how I can change these to black please?

Comment: The trick is to get hold of the Paint objects that are used and then set the colour there.  I don't remember the exact calls but there is support for getting the various different pain objects.

Comment: @Ifor Can u explain more please? not sure what you mean. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like

```
    mTripPlot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(my_colour);
```

For the label it would be something like

```
    mTripPlot.getDomainLabelWidget().getLabelPaint().setColor(my_colour);
```

Comment: I have this already, unfortunately it only changes the number labels along the axis not the actual text label. :(

Comment: Thank you very much will get testing this in the morning :)

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using the newer version of AndroidPlot (1.0 and above) this is the new way to update the text colour of the range and domain labels:

```
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.LEFT).getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM).getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempt the following:

```
plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainTickLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeTickLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginTickLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginTickLabelPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
```